# how to pass callback to onerror method globally?

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

i have a piece of code for IndexedDB

```
GetObj = function(storeName, key, callback){
    var db = indexedDB.db;
    if(db){
    var transaction = db.transaction([storeName], transactionType.READ_ONLY);  
    var obj = undefined;
    transaction.oncomplete = function(event) {              
        if(callback){
            callback(obj);
        }
    }; 
    var objectStore = transaction.objectStore(storeName);  
    var request = objectStore.get(key);  
    request.onerror = function (e){
        console.log("onError: in", e); 
        if (callback) {
            callback(-1);//error
        }       
    }
    request.onsuccess = function(event) {  
        obj = request.result;            
    };
   }    
}
```

I would like to define the request.onerror function globally so that i can reuse that function for all onerror (instead of copy pasting it all over the place). problem is howto pass callback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just define it in a higher scope:

```
var onerrorHandler = function (e, callback){
    console.log("onError: in", e); 
    if (callback) {
        callback(-1);//error
    }       
};
```

And then use that for the callback:

```
... snip
var request = objectStore.get(key);  
request.onerror = function (e) {
    onerrorHandler(e, callback);
};
... snip
```

Comment: Yeah i already tried this, This gives me error callback is undefined

Comment: will this be ok? since the onerror is expecting a signature of function (e)

Comment: @spiderdevil the anonymous is the handler and it takes the `e` parameter. you pass that, along with the callback, to your handler.

Comment: i take that back..seeing it again...signature is not changed but calling a function again...its clear now..i wish there was a way where we could just do request.onerror = onerrorHandler ,but oh well thanks

Answer (score -1):

I will rather avoid global error handler.

As you see, the code is not really reduce, but expended to include another wrapper function. In doing so, the error stack trace is not telling which request is causing error.

Comment: So how should I handle this if I don't want the same copy paste code all over the place?

Comment: It is the best solution. Copy paste is not not a hassle to me. gzip will compress them so don't worry about code size.